# sql table view problem

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and I am facing problems.  When I create any table, I can't view it.   Also, is it possible to enter the data into the table via management studio?

Like Harry 1234 xyz?

Comment: what database are you using? Post the script for your table. Where are you unable to view the table? What the heavens is `Harry 1234 xyz`?

Answer (score 1):

If you entered the query right, and it shows that the commands have been successfully executed, you should be able to see the created table with no entries by using `select * from table_name`.

If you still cannot see the data, try refreshing the database. Now you should be able to see your data.

Many database engines support entering data directly without SQL statements (like Harry 1234 xyz) like Microsoft SQL Server, MySql, etc. How you do it will depend on which database engine you're using.

Comment: Please write complete English words - this is not an IRC channel or an SMS message and abbreviation is not appreciated.

Comment: Sorry. I'll make sure not to use abrrevations the next time

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh "Object Explorer" in Management Studio.

It doesn't know that you created an object via SQL script